# I was there when you started

Tags: riddle

My first attempt at riddle.

> I was there when you started.
>
> You want me there at the end.
>
> I take a lot of time.
>
> And often - lots of space.
>
> I can be used for cheating
>
> I can be made of steel.
>
> Can share me with stranger
>
> But no one said you will

**What am I?**

Comment: A few more lines, and a couple of rhymes might turn your puzzle into a well-received... (well...) muzzle.

Comment: I agree with @Matsmath, I suggest that you make your riddle at least 6 lines, to ensure that it isn't too broad

Comment: Done. But the first version had two completely different right answers. Now only one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could you be

> the **bed**?

I was there when you started.

> People usually start the day by waking up in bed.

You want me there at the end.

> And most prefer to sleep at bed, when the day ends.

I take a lot of time.

> We spend considerable amount of our life in beds.

And often - lots of space.

> Beds range in size from infant cribs to king-sized platforms.

Comment: seems an answer existed here. :)

Comment: The cheating and stranger lines could be combined for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess......is it:

> Milestone?

I was there when you started.

> Yeah, you may set a milestone as the goal for everything before you start.

You want me there at the end.

> The milestone can be the end, or just the checkpoint of your goal.

I take a lot of time.

> Depends your visions of the milestone, it can be hardcore or easy for you.

And often - lots of space.

> Also, it depends your passion and ability for beat the challenge, it will costs for a week, a month...... can stated as 'space'.

:)